# Tensorflow 2.0 Identical model structure and hyper parameters result in different performance in different calling approaches

Tags: keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

there. I am a starter and learning Tensorflow 2.0. I have one model called in 3 different approaches. And the performances are different. Could anyone tell me why this is the case?

The model constructing and calling approach:

```
import os, sys

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, models, layers, regularizers, optimizers


def prepare_mnist_features_and_labels(x, y):
    x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32)/255.0
    y = tf.cast(y, tf.int64)
    return x, y


def mninst_dataset():
    (x_train, y_train), (x_eval, y_eval) = datasets.mnist.load_data()
    print('x_train/y_train shape:', x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
    y_train = tf.one_hot(y_train, depth=10)
    y_eval = tf.one_hot(y_eval, depth=10)

    ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
    ds_train = ds_train.map(prepare_mnist_features_and_labels)
    ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(x_train.shape[0]).batch(128)

    ds_eval = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_eval, y_eval))
    ds_eval = ds_eval.map(prepare_mnist_features_and_labels)
    ds_eval = ds_eval.shuffle(x_eval.shape[0]).batch(128)

    sample = next(iter(ds_train))
    print('sample: ', sample[0].shape, sample[1].shape)

    return ds_train, ds_eval


def main():
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

    trainset, evalset = mninst_dataset()

    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Reshape(target_shape=[28, 28, 1], input_shape=[28, 28]))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation=tf.nn.relu, strides=[1,1], padding="SAME"))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=[1,1], padding="SAME"))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation=tf.nn.relu, strides=[1,1], padding="SAME"))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=[2,2], padding="SAME"))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(units=10, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01), loss=tf.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(trainset.repeat(), epochs=30, steps_per_epoch=500,
              validation_data=evalset.repeat(), validation_steps=10)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The second approach to construct the model and run it is the following:

```
    import os, sys

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, models, layers, regularizers, optimizers

from tqdm import tqdm

def prepare_mnist_features_and_labels(x, y):
    x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32)/255.0
    y = tf.cast(y, tf.int64)
    return x, y


def mnist_dataset():
    (x_train, y_train), (x_eval, y_eval) = datasets.mnist.load_data()
     # y_train = tf.one_hot(y_train, depth=10)
    # y_eval = tf.one_hot(y_eval, depth=10)

    ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
    ds_train = ds_train.map(prepare_mnist_features_and_labels)
    # Test: replace x_train.shape[0] by the number of the training samples, which is 60000
    ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(x_train.shape[0]).batch(128)

    ds_eval = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_eval, y_eval))
    ds_eval = ds_eval.map(prepare_mnist_features_and_labels)
    ds_eval = ds_eval.shuffle(x_eval.shape[0]).batch(128)

    # sample = next(iter(ds_train))
    # print('sample: ', sample[0].shape, sample[1].shape)

    return ds_train, ds_eval

# tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels, logits, name=None):
# labels: Tensof of shape [d_0, d_1, ..., d_{r-1}]. Each label must be an index in [0, num_classes]
# logits: Unscaled of log probabilities of shape [d_0, d_1, ..., d_{r-1}, num_classes]
# A common use is to have logits of shape [batch_size, num_classes] and have labels of shape [batch_size]
def compute_loss(logits, labels):
    # print(logits.numpy())
    # print(labels.numpy())
    return tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
             labels=labels, logits=logits
                )
            )


def compute_accuracy(logits, labels):
    predictions = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1)
    # print(predictions)
    # print(labels)
    # print(list(zip(predictions.numpy(), labels.numpy())))
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(predictions, labels), tf.float32))


def train_one_step(model, optimizer, x, y):
    # At each train step, first calculate the forward loss
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = model(x)
        loss = compute_loss(logits, y)

    # Then calculate the backward gradients over each trainable variables
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    # Optimize and update variables throught backpropagation
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

    # Compute current model accuracy
    accuracy = compute_accuracy(logits, y)

    return loss, accuracy


def train(epoch, model, optimizer, trainset):
#def train(epoch, model, optimizer):
    # trainset = mnist_dataset()[0]
    loss = 0.0
    accuracy = 0.0

    #for step, (x, y) in enumerate(tqdm(trainset)):
    for step, (x, y) in enumerate(tqdm(trainset)):
        loss, accuracy = train_one_step(model, optimizer, x, y)

        if step % 110 == 0:
            print('epoch', epoch, ': loss', loss.numpy(), '; accuracy', accuracy.numpy())

    return loss, accuracy


class MyModel(keras.Model):


    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation=tf.nn.relu, strides=[1,1], padding="SAME", input_shape=(-1, 28, 28, 1))
        self.layer2 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=[1,1], padding="SAME")
        self.layer3 = layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation=tf.nn.relu, strides=[1,1], padding="SAME")
        self.layer4 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=[2,2], padding="SAME")
        self.layer5 = layers.Flatten()
        self.layer6 = layers.Dense(units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))
        self.layer7 = layers.Dense(units=10, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))


    def call(self, x, training=False):
        x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, 28, 28, 1))
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        x = self.layer3(x)
        x = self.layer4(x)
        x = self.layer5(x)
        x = self.layer6(x)
        x = self.layer7(x)
        return x


def main():

    # set random seed
    tf.random.set_seed(22)    

    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

    trainset, evalset = mnist_dataset()

    model = MyModel()

    optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)

    # Save checkpoints with keras api as the first approach
    # Save checkpoints manually as a second approach.
    # find a way to implement early-stopping strategy in the programming style

    # for epoch in tqdm(range(30)):
    for epoch in range(50):
        loss, accuracy = train(epoch, model, optimizer, trainset)

    print('Final epoch', epoch, ': loss', loss.numpy(), '; accuracy', accuracy.numpy())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the last approach is below:

```
import os, sys

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, models, layers, regularizers, optimizers

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def prepare_mnist_features_and_labels(x, y):
    x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32)/255.0
    y = tf.cast(y, tf.int64)
    return x, y


def mnist_dataset():
    (x_train, y_train), (x_eval, y_eval) = datasets.mnist.load_data()
    print('x_train/y_train shape:', x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
    y_train = tf.one_hot(y_train, depth=10)
    y_eval = tf.one_hot(y_eval, depth=10)

    ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
    ds_train = ds_train.map(prepare_mnist_features_and_labels)
    ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(x_train.shape[0]).batch(128)

    ds_eval = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_eval, y_eval))
    ds_eval = ds_eval.map(prepare_mnist_features_and_labels)
    ds_eval = ds_eval.shuffle(x_eval.shape[0]).batch(128)

    sample = next(iter(ds_train))
    print('sample: ', sample[0].shape, sample[1].shape)

    return ds_train, ds_eval


class MyModel(keras.Model):

    # self.model = keras.Sequential([
    #     layers.Reshape(target_shape=(28*28, ), input_shape=(28, 28)),
    #     layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    #     layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    #     layers.Desnse(10)
    # ])
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation=tf.nn.relu, strides=[1,1], padding="SAME", input_shape=(-1, 28, 28, 1))
        self.layer2 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=[1,1], padding="SAME")
        self.layer3 = layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation=tf.nn.relu, strides=[1,1], padding="SAME")
        self.layer4 = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=[2,2], padding="SAME")
        self.layer5 = layers.Flatten()
        self.layer6 = layers.Dense(units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))
        self.layer7 = layers.Dense(units=10, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))


    def call(self, x, training=False):
        x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, 28, 28, 1))
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        x = self.layer3(x)
        x = self.layer4(x)
        x = self.layer5(x)
        x = self.layer6(x)
        x = self.layer7(x)
        return x


def main():
    tf.random.set_seed(22)

    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

    trainset, evalset = mnist_dataset()

    model = MyModel()
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), loss=tf.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(trainset.repeat(), epochs=30, steps_per_epoch=500, verbose=1,
              validation_data=evalset.repeat(), validation_steps=10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Each of them take a while to train. Can anyone tell me why the performances are different? And in the future how I should debug by myself?

Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved after carefully examine the network. It turn out that the last fully connected layer in the model was activated with a relu function, which in not appropriate. And the choice of loss function tf.losses.categoricalCrossentropy and tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits also make a big difference. No matter what get chosen, Make sure the loss function and the final output of the network match.